# How to support %x formatting on a class that emulates int

Tags: python, string-formatting

I haven't seen a way to do this. I am in Python 3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5050, Mar 21 2017, 01:21:04). MacOS under Sierra, though we'll need this to work on Python 2.

I have a custom class which does something which looks like an int with subfield decoding. For my own reasons, I want to be able to do things both like

```
inst * 4
```

and

```
inst.subfield << 1
```

(where subfield is an attribute of inst). These objects are highly overloaded, and e.g. printing `inst` will dump the subfields for viewing.

This is all done by overloading all the custom functions to handle the math and interaction with other objects. In general, it works really well, with one glaring exception: printing. For the most part, a user can forget this isn't really an integer and use it like one, but using the integer print commands won't work:

```
print("%#x"%inst)
TypeError: %x format: an integer is required, not CustomType
```

I do have `__int__` overloaded, and `int(inst)` returns an integer as expected.

Is there any way to make this work? It's a minor annoyance, but one I'd like to fix.

Also, I do have `__format__` implemented. So `'{0:x}'.format(inst)` works, but the print above doesn't.

Thanks!

Comment: you have to define `__format__` not `__int__`

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Works just fine as long as you implement `__int__` (in both python 2 and 3).

Comment: Really @Aran-Fey? I'm getting an error: https://ideone.com/J8vwri.

Comment: What version of Python are you using, Corley?

Comment: Python 3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5050, Mar 21 2017, 01:21:04). MacOS under Sierra.

Comment: @ChristianDean Weird, on repl.it it only works in python 2, but on my local machine it works in both python 3.4.0 and python 3.6.4 (for reference, repl.it uses python 3.6.1.)

Comment: hmm, ok let me go try python 3.6.4 and see if it's a bug that was fixed....

Comment: Huh, this is weird @Aran-Fey. On my local machine, it raises a `TypeError` in Python 3.6.1, Python 3.6.3, and Python 2.7. Perhaps something was added in Python 3.6.4?

Comment: @ChristianDean Nevermind, I'm a potato. I accidentally tested it in 3.4 twice :(

Comment: I tried 3.6.4 (Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48ecebad5, Dec 18 2017, 21:07:28)), no change. However, I did find something interesting: `'%d'` works, `'%x'` doesn't. Maybe something specific to hex output; I'll edit the question.

Comment: lol, that's fine @Aran-Fey :) I think I'll do a bit of digging to see if something was introduced in Python 3.5 that previous versions didn't have.

Comment: @ChristianDean: [The problematic code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L14317) has different code paths for the `o`/`x`/`X` format codes than for other integers. Either way, `PyNumber_Check` is called (which demands the equivalent of `__int__` or `__float__` exist), but then `o`/`x`/`X` do type conversion with `PyNumber_Index` (which only cares about `__index__`), while the other integer type codes use `PyNumber_Long` (which uses `__int__` if provided, without looking for `__index__`). That's why `%d` doesn't have the problem (only needs `__int__`).

Comment: Ah okay. Thanks @ShadowRanger.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to implement [`__int__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__int__) and [`__index__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__index__):

```
class X(object):
    def __int__(self):
        return 42
    def __index__(self):
        return 42

x = X()
print('%#x' % x)
```

output:

```
0x2a
```

From the docs for [`__index__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__index__):

> Called to implement operator.index(), and whenever Python needs to
>   losslessly convert the numeric object to an integer object (such as in
>   slicing, **or in the built-in bin(), hex() and oct() functions**).
>   Presence of this method indicates that the numeric object is an
>   integer type. Must return an integer.

So `__index__` is called by `hex()`, as can be seen by looking at the relevant source code in [PyNumber_ToBase](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f320be77ffb73e3b9e7fc98c37b8df3975d84b40/Objects/abstract.c#L1481).

Comment: Maybe a bit of explanation? :-) This does work, but I'm a bit curios to know why `__index__` is needed. Seems pretty unrelated.

Comment: Same here... amazingly enough this does the trick, but is not intuitive at all :)

Comment: Does adding `__index__` somehow make Python recognize instances of `X` as integers?

Comment: `__int__` represents a way to cast to an integer, but it is assumed it could be lossy, as in "the object itself" may not be an int. When `__index__` returns an integer, the convention is to believe that this integer "really is" the object (which is still not actually true, but allows it to proceed with integer-requiring operations, like being used as a slice index, or for `hex`, etc.).

Comment: _"So I guess `__index__` is called by hex()"_ - Yup, your right. [Here's the relevant line of CPython code if you want to incorporate it](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f320be77ffb73e3b9e7fc98c37b8df3975d84b40/Objects/abstract.c#L1481).

Comment: Strangely, on Python 3, both `__int__` and `__index__` are needed; on Py2, only `__int__` is needed. It would have made sense if Py3 needed `__index__` and Py2 needed `__int__`, but it looks like the formatting accidentally demands that `__index__` be there (to support the actual conversion) and `__int__` be there (because `PyNumber_Check` only accepts things with the slot corresponding to `__int__` or `__float__`, not checking for `__index__`). On Py2, the conversion and type check both look for `__int__`.